# ValidatorUtils of list inside a list

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm currently making some validations in my code and one of the main problem is I have a object list that has another object list and so on.

```
public class BigObject{
    private Long idObject;
    private String idLanguage;
    private Date dateGeneration;
    private List<FirstObject> firstObject;
    //getters and setters

}

public class FirstObject{
    private List<SecondObject> secondObject;
    //getters and setters
}

public class SecondObject{
    private Long order;
    private String titol;
    private int floatProperty;
    //getters and setters
}
```

These are my classes and their are inside of another. I set up my Validator in the Main and created their respective class, now, in the validator class I have this:

```
public class BigObjectValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return BigObject.class.equals(clazz)
        || FirstObject.class.equals(clazz)
        || SecondObject.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        BigObject bigObject = (BigObject) obj;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(e, "idObject", "empty.id");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(e, "idLanguage", "empty.id");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(e, "dateGeneration", "empty.id");
        if (!(bigObject.getFirstObject().isEmpty())) {
            for (FirstObject firstObject : bigObject.getFirstObject()) {
                if (firstObject.getSecondObject() != null) {
                    for (SecondObject secondObject : firstObject.getSecondObject()) {
                        if (secondObject != null){
                            validateSecondObject(secondObject,e);
                        }
                    }
                }           
            }           
        }
    }
    private void validateSecondObject(SecondObject secondObject, Errors e) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(e, "order", "order.empty");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(e, "titol", "order.empty");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(e, "floatProperty", "order.empty");
    }
}
```

The main problem is I'm getting a `org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'order' of bean class` I'm trying to guess why is that, its because the validator is set up in the BigObject class and not the other ones. Now I don't know if I have to create another class inside BigObjectValidator or something like that.

Edit:

Main

```
        try{
        BigObject object = new BigObject();
        List<FirstObject> firstObj = ArrayList<FirstObject>;
        SecondObject secondObj = new SecondObject();

        object.getIdObject("something");
        object.getIdLanguage("En");
        object.getDateGeneration("05-18-2018");

        secondObject.setOrder(null);
        firstObj.set(1,secondObject);
        BeanPropertyBindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(je.getValue(), "Object");
        BigObjectValidator validateObject = new BigObjectValidator();
        validateObject.validate(object, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()){
            System.out.println(result.getAllErrors().toString());
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Comment: please attach a usage example, this is a runtime error. 
Also, You clearly support only BigObject validation (due to explicit cast in the beggining of the method) so why does your supports() method allow those other classes?

Comment: I transform an XML object stored in string inside the BigObject, so in order to make it simple I added manually the values, this sure should works in order to reproduce the error. I named it that way because BigObject stored the other classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look here 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html

> public interface Errors Stores and exposes information about
>   data-binding and validation errors **for a specific object**. Field names
>   can be properties of the target object (e.g. "name" when binding to a
>   customer object), or nested fields in case of subobjects (e.g.
>   "address.street"). Supports subtree navigation via
>   setNestedPath(String): for example, an AddressValidator validates
>   "address", not being aware that this is a subobject of customer.

If you pass the same Errors object to your validateSecondObject method, it still references the original obj, not your firstObject.. You must validate this differently. Either get a new instance of Errors (eg. org.springframework.validation.BindException) or do it by manually throwing exceptions

Comment: Creating another BeanPropertyBindingResult named "Object" and attached the new object solves the problem. Thanks